# Where can I access raw values for near infra red absorbance of liquid water?

Tags: water, spectrophotometry

I have encountered several sites where water's near-infra-red absorption spectra has been plotted as a figure (for e.g, [here](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_vibrational_spectrum.html)). Is there a site where I can access these raw absorbance/transmittance values? Eyeballing is prone to errors and inaccuracies.

What I have found: [NIST](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7732185&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=1#IR-SPEC) has a nice plot of the IR absorption spectra of liquid water, and I can potentially access the raw data by looking at the plotting functions, but as you can see it has no near-IR data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a database called [HITRAN](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/) that offers what I wanted. They support a python API that can be used to pull the relevant data. The code I used is written below (you'll need the hapi.py file from [here](http://hitran.org/static/hapi/hapi.py)).

```
from hapi import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fetch('H2O',1,1,7500,11500)
nu,coef = absorptionCoefficient_Lorentz(SourceTables='H2O')
plt.plot(nu,coef)
plt.show()
```